# confusion about tokio/bytes::BytesMut

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

from the [doc](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.BytesMut.html):

> BytesMut represents a unique view into a potentially shared memory region. Given the uniqueness guarantee, **owners of BytesMut handles are able to mutate the memory**.

> BytesMut can be thought of as containing a buf: Arc<Vec>, an offset into buf, a slice length, and a guarantee that no other BytesMut for the same buf overlaps with its slice. **That guarantee means that a write lock is not required.**

1. why multiple owners of BytesMut can mutate the memory concurrently?
2. why a write lock is not required?
3. how is it implemented?

Answer (score 2):

> why multiple owners of BytesMut can mutate the memory concurrently?
> why a write lock is not required?

From the docs: **and a guarantee that no other BytesMut for the same buf overlaps with its slice.**

There is no overlap, so it is safe to mutate it since **no one else can mutate that region**. Also no lock need for the same reason, no synchronization is needed since there is no overlap.

> how is it implemented?

You can take a look at the [source code](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/src/bytes/bytes_mut.rs.html#60-65)